# Upload canvas image to the server and save to file

Tags: c#, html, image, canvas

I want to upload a canvas image and save it as a .png file on the server, which uses webapi.

I have figured out a means to upload a dataurl as a string to the server.  I have tried making a byte[] from that and saving it, but when I open the file with paint it tells me I have a corrupted file.

```
client:
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

Server:
    string strData = postParam.dataURL.Substring("data:image/png;base64,".Length);
    List<byte> src = new List<byte>();

    for (int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++)
    {
    char c = strData[i];
    byte b = Convert.ToByte(c);
    src.Add(b);
    }

    System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(@"D:\git\Lens\Lens.Server.UI.HTML5\reports\chartImages\hello.png", 100000, System.IO.FileOptions.None);
                System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(fs);
                bw.Write(src.ToArray());
```

So I think my question is , is the byte[] of the image datasource even the right thing to store in an png file or do I do something else.  Then if so I have to convert my string correctly which I might be screwing up too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the base64 string part of the data uri

```
string strData = postParam.dataURL.Substring("data:image/png;base64,".Length);
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(strData);
```